# How to replace substring of numeric value using awk

Tags: awk, substring

I have a requirement to replace the middle 6 digits with numeric '9' in the below 16 digit numeric field using awk.Please let me know the solution as i started now on awk

Delimiter: `|`

Actual data in file :

```
2006-07-27|0|DBT|||6657832345233037|Y
```

Expected data in a file:

```
2006-07-27|0|DBT|||6657839999993037|Y
```

Answer (score 3):

`awk` to the rescue!

**UPDATE** you have to set `OFS` to preserve the delimiter.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} {$6=substr($6,1,6) "999999" substr($6,13)}1'
```

Comment: awk -F '|' 'BEGIN{OFS="|"}{$6=substr($6,1,6) "999999" substr($6,13)}1'

Comment: What do 1,6, and 13 in substr($6,1,6) and substr($6,13) mean? Thank you.

Comment: http://thomas-cokelaer.info/blog/2011/05/awk-the-substr-command-to-select-a-substring/

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, here is another alternative:

```
awk -F'|' '$6 = gensub(/^(.{6}).{6}/,"\\1999999",1,$6)' OFS="|"
```